# WSO2 APIM gateway is setting Host header as host:port

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

APIM gateway is setting Host header as host:port to call backend, like this:

> GET /api/category HTTP/1.1
>  Accept-Language:
>   en-US,en;q=0.8,pt;q=0.6
>  token:
>   6785ea7b-#######-#######-93f06834660a
>  Accept-Encoding: gzip,
>   deflate, sdch
>  X-Forwarded-Server: server01
>  X-Forwarded-For:
>   172.XX.XXX.XX
>  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)
>  Postman-Token: ece4261e-d610-655c-f06c-f24a99f007c8
>  Accept:
>   */*
>  X-Forwarded-Host: server01
>  Cache-Control: no-cache
>   **Host: api.empresa.net:80**
>  Connection: Keep-Alive

This causes problems with Web Application Firewall, how can I change this?
Enviroment: RedHat Linux 6.7, APIM 1.9.1

Thanks

Comment: Are you saying API Gateway should not set any Host header? Or are you saying API Gateway should not set port in Host header?

Comment: Sorry for the too late message, I fixed the problem, I changed the policy in the WAF, now the policy not verify the Host header only by host, but host:port, and yes, I wanted to remove the port of Host header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know your pain.  We were running into the same problem with our load balancer.  I believe there is a fix coming from WSO2 for this.  In the meantime, you will need to create a custom "in" sequence under "/_system/governance/apimgt/customsequences/in" with the following content:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="remove_port_In"> 
  <property name="REQUEST_HOST_HEADER" value="api.empresa.net" scope="axis2"/>
</sequence>
```

You can then associate this with your API as an inbound custom sequence through the publisher application prior to publishing.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [protocol specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html),

> The Host request-header field specifies the Internet host and port
>   number of the resource being requested, as obtained from the original
>   URI given by the user or referring resource.
>
> ```
>    Host = "Host" ":" host [ ":" port ] ; Section 3.2.2
> ```
>
> A "host" without any trailing port information implies the default
>   port for the service requested (e.g., "80" for an HTTP URL). For
>   example, a request on the origin server for
>   http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/ would properly include:
>
> ```
>    GET /pub/WWW/ HTTP/1.1
>    Host: www.w3.org
> ```